# How to return a text value from a column that appears the fewest number of times in the same row of a second column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out a way to use a single formula to return the value from column 1 that appears the fewest number of times in column 2 in the same row.

If column 1 represents a person assigned to a task and column 2 represents the person who actually completed the task, I want to be able to return the person who completed the fewest number of assigned tasks.

An image is below for reference.

[image: An example of the two columns and ultimate result]

I've tried a combination of ARRAYFORMULA and IF to check if column 1 matches column 2 but I can't figure out how to return the text value from column 1 with the fewest matches in the same row in column 2.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=choosecols(sortn(map(unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,countif(A:A,Σ)-countif(B:B,Σ)})),1,1,2,),1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks for this. I've never seen a sigma in a formula before. Is that just a placeholder in the LAMBDA function?

Comment: Its just an identifier I used; you may change it to your convenience...

Answer (score 0):

A little bit messy, but:

```
=index(sortn(LET(z,A:B,y,INDEX(z,,1),i,INDEX(z,,2),j,UNIQUE(y),HSTACK(j,BYROW(j,LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(((y=x)*(i<>x))))))),1,,2,0),,1)
```

Result:

[image]